# Python: Calling subclass's method within super method call

Tags: python

**EDIT: My assumptions were wrong; the code below does in fact work like I wanted it to. The behaviour I was observing turned out to be caused by another bit of the code I was working with that I overlooked because it looked completely unrelated.**

So I have some code structured like this:

```
class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        print "spam"

    def bar(self):
        do_something()
        self.foo()
        do_something_else()

class C(B):
    def foo(self):
        print "ham"

    def bar(self):
        super(C, self).bar()
        print "eggs"

c = C()
c.bar()
```

This would do_something(), print "spam", do_something_else(), and then print "eggs". However, what I *want* to do is do_something(), print "ham", do_something_else(), and then print "eggs". In other words, I want to call B's bar method from C's bar method, but I want *it* to call C's foo method, not B's.

Is there a way to do this? Note that in the actual code I'm dealing with, both the B class and the code that actually calls c.bar() are part of an evolving third-party library, so mucking with that would be a last resort.

Comment: This does what you want... I don't see the problem.

Comment: So you can only write and modify `C`, right?

Comment: I think the example code already does what you want - for me it prints 'ham' and then 'eggs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted does what you want.

When `B.bar` calls `self.foo()` when `self` is an object of type `C`, it will call `C.foo`.

This works because `self.foo` is looked up first on `self` then on `self`'s actual type's method-resolution-order C3-linearised class-and-base-classes tuple (here `(C, B, object)`).  This will return `C.foo` before `B.foo`.

Comment: Huh. The actual code isn't working out that way, and I could only conclude super() led to treating the object as if it were an instance of the superclass. Something else must be going on, then, but I have no clue what it might be. Thanks for clarifying this issue, anyway.